# why do i get network is unreachable error in my smtp program?

Tags: python-3.x, smtp

```
import smtplib

fromadd = 'xyz@gmail.com'
to = fromadd
data = 'hello'

server = smtplib.SMTP('www.gmail.com')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.login(fromadd,'pwd')
server.sendmail(fromadd, to, data)
server.quit()
```

in the program above, i always got OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable error message on my screen when i execute it, why does this happen and how to correct it?

Comment: Because `www.gmail.com` does not accept emails (or even smpt connections).

Comment: I hope that isn't your real email, xD

Answer (score 0):

In your program, you tell it to connect to `www.gmail.com`, but that domain is not an email server, as I and @marcelm noticed. Try using just `gmail.com` or `mail.google.com`.

Comment: Still your firewall or ISP could be blocking the SMTP port.

Comment: @tripleee I haven't heard of a firewall or ISP blocking email... that is crazy. That couldn't possibly be the case for the OP. I assume that the OP can access his email on his network.

Comment: Outbound SMTP is pretty much universally blocked from home consumer netblocks as an anti-spam measure. You basically can't run a mail server on a home ADSL any longer becaue spammers poisoned that well (too). These days, with authenticated SMTP taking over hon a different port numdber), it's less of an issue, but if you test code which needs port 25, it won't work.

Comment: @tripleee He isn't running a mail server; he's connecting to gmail.

Comment: That was just an example. I understand the question.