# How do i troubleshoot this particular issue while sending mail via smtp using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp

my code is working locally. But it is showing a number of error message after pushing python anywhere cloud and console is showing OSError: (Errno 101) Network is unreachable smtp.
i have attached console messages along with it

```
18:47 ~ $ python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raja4656/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    with open(file_path) as sample_letter_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'letter_templates\\letter_3.txt'
18:48 ~ $ python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raja4656/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    with open(file_path) as sample_letter_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'letter_templates\\letter_3.txt'
18:49 ~ $ python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raja4656/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.live.com", 587) as connection:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 843, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 831, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

my mail provider server is outlook which is smtp.live.com and using port 587 . here is the codelink

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/raja4656/files/home/raja4656/main.py?edit

Comment: Maybe you wanna take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185294/why-do-i-get-network-is-unreachable-error-in-my-smtp-program

Comment: You could also had the relevant part of your code as snippet for us to better understand the error

Comment: Possibly relevant https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SMTPForFreeUsers